# Problems setting div content alignment

Tags: html, css, variables, math, calculated-field

I want to add an info bar to a page. It contains three divs horizontally aligned and all content is currently floating left within them.
I'm trying to make the content of the center div align center and the right-hand div align to the right, but nothing I try seems to be working.

I've tried adding `text-align:center` to `#delivery` and `text-align:right` to `#quickshop` and I also tried `float:right` on `#quickshop` but they have no effect at all.

HTML/CSS:

```css
#info-bar {
    height: 46px;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 82%;
}
.info {
    float: left;
    width: 37.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
#quickquotes.info {
    width: 28.5%;
}
#quickshop.info {
    width: 34%;
}
#container i {
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #a6d120;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#container i:before {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
.icon-quote:before { content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27"); }
.icon-delivery:before { content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27"); }
.icon-quickshop:before { content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27"); }

#container .text-area {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #1e3e57;
    letter-spacing: 0.07em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-bar">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="quickquotes" class="info">
      <i class="icon-quote"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Quick Quote Fast Response</div>
    </div>

    <div id="delivery" class="info">
      <i class="icon-delivery"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Free UK Delivery on Orders Over £100</div>
    </div>

    <div id="quickshop" class="info">
      <i class="icon-quickshop"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Quick Shop Search Product Codes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've set up a fiddle here so you can see a real-world example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/qafru72o/2/

Where on earth am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `text-align:left;` from `#container .text-area` and then add `justify-content` to each individual div.

```css
#info-bar{
    height: 46px;
}
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:82%;
}
.info{
    float:left;
    width:37.5%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 9px 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
#quickquotes.info{
    width:28.5%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
#quickshop.info{
    width:34%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
} 
#delivery.info{
    justify-content: center;
}
#container i {
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #a6d120;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#container i:before {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
.icon-quote:before     {content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27");}
.icon-delivery:before  {content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27");}
.icon-quickshop:before {content: url("http://placehold.it/35x27");}

#container .text-area {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color:#1e3e57;
    letter-spacing:0.07em;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-bar">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="quickquotes" class="info">
      <i class="icon-quote"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Quick Quote Fast Response</div>
    </div>

    <div id="delivery" class="info">
      <i class="icon-delivery"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Free UK Delivery on Orders Over £100</div>
    </div>

    <div id="quickshop" class="info">
      <i class="icon-quickshop"></i>
      <div class="text-area">
        Quick Shop Search Product Codes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is this what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. If you inspect element on #quickshop you can see that both the icon and the text are still to the left of the containing div. I need all the content of that div to be positioned to the right, and all the content of #delivery to be positioned in the center of the div

Comment: i edited the code. can you check if that is correct?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I'll study what you did so I learn for next time I come across this issue

Comment: no problem bro. can you mark this as the answer? :) thanks!

Comment: Ok, I understand what you did. Removed text-align:left; from #container .text-area and then added justify-content to each individual div. Nice and simple and now I'm kicking myself for not even thinking of that.